# Filter out specific value without excluding the NULL rows

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I have the following table and I want to filter out a specific value but keeping the null (empty) rows.

```
category       sell
Apple           1
Orange          3
Banana          2
null            1
Orange          2
null            1
```

I tried different ways but the query kept filtering out the *null* rows. For example, I only want to filter out the rows with the orange, the output table should be:

```
category       sell
Apple           1
Banana          2
null            1
null            1

SELECT *
FROM table AS t 
WHERE t."sell"  NOT IN ('Orange')
```

I also tried with

```
WHERE t."sell"  != 'Orange'
```

OR

```
WHERE t."sell"  NOT LIKE '%Orange%'
```

All of the returned results exclude the rows with the null value. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: tag your database, which dbms are you using?

Comment: @eshirvana I am using Redshift

Comment: `OR <column> IS NULL`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert ah no you are right - it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this schema:

```
create table transaction(
  category varchar(15),
  sell int
)

insert into transaction(category, sell)
values('Apple',1), ('Orange',3), ('Banana',2), (null,1), ('Orange',2), (null,1)
```

You could use:

```
select *
from transaction
where category != 'Orange'
   or category is null
```

Which results in:

```
category    sell
Apple       1
Banana      2
null        1
null        1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `COALESCE` OR `NVL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS t 
WHERE COALESCE(t.category,'[notfruit]') NOT IN ('Orange')
```

Comment: Thank you the above approach suggested by gbeaven works but I will also try your approach!

Answer (score 0):

Redshift does not support an explicit `NULL`-safe equality operator.  But you can easily emulate it using:

```
where (fruit = 'Orange') is not true
```

`is not true` handles `NULL` values in line with most people's intuition -- i.e. does not return `NULL` but recognizes that they are not true.

The SQL Standard (and Postgres nowadays) supports the official such comparison:

```
where fruit is distinct from 'Orange'
```

However, Redshift does not support this syntax.